# Do you need to have a Diablo 3 account and character to post on Blizzard forums?

Tags: diablo-iii

I am trying to post on the Blizzard forums but it gives me the error "No character was found".

I don't want to use my bought account linked to my real Diablo 3 character for security reasons. We all know how often forums get hacked and user names and hashes posted publicly. Should that happen I don't want it to relate to my real playing account.

I have another account which has a "BattleTag" account and one post I saw said this was required to be able to post on the forums, not necessarily a bought game and character, but this is not working for me.

**EDIT** To those that told me it uses the "same system" I understand what you are trying to say; in that it authenticates with the same credentials. But let me put it this way; if the forums go down, or D3 game goes down, you are trying to tell me they use the same system, so they both go down. Not the case is it.

Comment: Using an authenticator should prevent your account from being hacked even in the event of a database leak. So unless you use your password on other sites, that should be enough protection.

Comment: Your worry about security is sort of pointless.  The Battle.net forums uses the EXACT same authentication server as Diablo 3 does.  Yes...You need a license in order to post on the forums.  the license cannot be a "Trial" and/or "Starter" account.

Answer (score 4):

There is no such thing as anonymous posting on the Battle.net forums. They are not public forums. They are a deep-rooted part of the Battle.net system which requires you to have an active, paid Battle.net account in order to participate.

As for your "security reasons," the Battle.net forums cannot be independently compromised. It is a part of the Battle.net system and does not have a separate authentication system from the rest of Battle.net services. Using the forums does not put your account at risk.

Comment: As I stated, the forums *cannot* be independently compromised. The Battle.net forums are not third-party software.

Comment: And you're still not making any sense. I believe we have different definitions of compromised. What would being third-party or not have to do with whether something can be hacked or not? If the forums are hacked, and my password hash is cracked, and my email address is in plaintext...what's stopping that same creds being used on the D3 game client (without 2 factor auth)? (apart from maybe past IP & region irregularity checking)

Comment: I think he is talking about crosssite scripting and similar problems. Just open the forum in another Browser and you are fine. (e.g. use Chrome for normal browsing and Firefox for Bnet forum)

Comment: @kindascrewed It's obvious that you have no idea what you are talking about. I don't mean to offend, but it's important that you realize that you are looking at the situation incorrectly. Battle.net uses one authentication method. This is shared between the website and all of the games. All of them go through the same system. If you believe that your browser is compromised or that your computer is compromised, that's a different issue entirely. But there is nothing about the **forums** that puts you at risk.

Comment: @kindascrewedbyblizzard - Stop Trolling.  Your account cannot be compromised.  The forums cannot be compromised, and if they are, your actual account already is compromised ( same system ).  Stop worrying about NOTHING.

Comment: @Ramhound: This is not quite true. It is possible to hijack your account by some nasty JavaScript exploits. If you have a tab open where you are currently logged into the forum and visit some dubious warez site (through a fake link), then someone might hijack your current session and change your account information. It is not very likely, but it is possible.

Comment: @ayckoster It's a bit more complex than that. I assume by "JavaScript exploit," you are revisiting the cross-site scripting you mentioned. XSS *requires* a vulnerability in the target website. Considering Blizzard has been at the forefront of account security in recent years, it's safe to assume that Battle.net is secure.

Comment: @Koviko: The mere fact that they list it [on their official security site](http://us.battle.net/support/en/article/account-and-computer-security) under "Web Browsing Safety" shows that they cannot completely prevent it and the site is is **not** secure. I agree that they have very high security standards though.

Answer (score 3):

**Short Answer**: You don't need to own Diablo 3, but you do need to own one of: *Starcraft 2*, *Diablo 3*, or *World of Warcraft*.  In the event you own World of Warcraft, the account needs to be in good standing as well.

---

**Long Answer**: In order to post on the Bnet forums, you not only need to log in to Battle.net, but you also need to choose one of your Accounts/Games to post as.  For instance, the first time I logged in, it chose my (very old and neglected) WoW account.  Since I haven't played that for several years, and the subscription is long since past, I can't post using that account.  Switching to my Diablo 3 account, though, made it nice and easy to post.

It does look like you have to own at least one of Blizzard's more recent games (WoW, SC2, or D3) in order to post on their forums.  If you choose your WoW account, it also has to be in good standing.

To choose your "account" on the D3 forums.  You will see this:

[image]

Use this to login with the account you created.  After doing so, that same area will turn into a "character select" section.  This is where you should be able to choose your D3/SC2 battle tag account.  Select the account, and you are now posting as that account.

Comment: I can click that image where you say and login - but I can't select the BattleTag I created for the job, (or anything for that matter), so I suppose i'm screwed.

Comment: You can't post on Blizzard forums without using the account that owns at least one of their more recent games.  It doesn't have to be D3, but, yes, you do have to own *something* of theirs.

Comment: Yes you are correct. How sad, when in reality, I do own one of their games, I just don't trust their security...

Comment: If you don't trust Blizzard's security, then why do you play their games?  As @Koviko said, their forums *cannot* be comprised independently.  It's an all or nothing deal with Battle.net.